# Finding the SHA1's of all objects in a commit git

Tags: git

Is there a way to retrieve all the SHA1's for all objects (blobs and trees) inside of a particular commit in git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `git rev-list` will do what you want:

```
git rev-list --no-walk <commit> --objects
```

See the documentation on `git rev-list` for more information at http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html.

***Edit:** Added `--no-walk` as per Paŭlo Ebermann's suggestion; this will only show the objects for the given ref, without the ancestor commits.*

Comment: I suppose you want `git rev-list --no-walk <commit> --objects` instead - it gives you only one commit, instead of a commit and all its parents.

Comment: That would be even better. ;]